# Stop form from redirecting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This question has been asked and answered quite a few different times. I've searched around SO and couldn't find a solution that worked. I tried `e.preventdefault()` and `return false`. Neither worked. Then I saw that I need to go back to AJAX and can't use a promise and I refuse to do so and I refuse to think that there isn't a way to do it with promises.

Anyway,

Code:

```
var submitDataForm = function () {
    console.log("button called");


    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var first = document.getElementById('first-name');
    var last = document.getElementById('last-name');
    var web = document.getElementById('domain');
    var city = document.getElementById('city');
    var obj = document.getElementById('obj');
    var describe = document.getElementById('describe');
    var brandpower = document.getElementById('brandpower');

    if (email.checkValidity() && first.checkValidity() && web.checkValidity() && city.checkValidity() && obj.checkValidity()) {
        var emailV = email.value;
        var firstV = first.value;
        var webV = (web.value == undefined) ? 'null' : web.value;
        var cityV = city.value;
        var objV = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
        var describeV = (describe && describe.options && describe.selectedIndex) ? describe.options[describe.selectedIndex].value : describe.value;
        var brandpowerV = (brandpower && brandpower.options && brandpower.selectedIndex) ? brandpower.options[brandpower.selectedIndex].value : brandpower.value;
        var radio = jQuery('input[name="dealer"]:checked').val();


        jQuery.post("/form-one/?" + "email=" + emailV + "&first=" + firstV +
                cityV + "&domain=" + webV + "&obj=" + objV + "&describe=" + describeV + "&brandpower=" + brandpowerV +
                "&radio=" + radio, function () {
                    console.log("data sent");
                })
                .done(function () {
                    console.log("data success");
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    console.log("data failed");
                })
                .always(function () {
                    console.log("data finished");
                    email.value, first.value, web.value, city.value, obj.value, describe.value, brandpower.value = "";
//window.location.href = "/";
                });
    } else {
        $('#error').css('display', 'block').delay(5000).queue(function (next) {
            jQuery('#error').fadeOut('slow').css('display', 'none');
        });
    }
}


<button id="next" class="green-button" onClick="submitDataForm()">Next</button>
```

Again, I'm trying to have the form do nothing but submit data (will add custom events later) without refresh or reload.

Thank you!

Comment: *"I refuse to think that there isn't a way to do it with promises."* -  I don't see what promises have to do with this one way or the other. *"I need to go back to AJAX"* - What do you mean "back to"? The code shown uses Ajax and doesn't cancel any default behaviour of the button, and given that the button is a submit button if it is in a form it will submit that form.

Comment: Do you have just plain `<button>`  but not `<button type="submit">`?

Plain button WILL NOT cause form submission - provide exact code that you have there.

Comment: @c-smile - If the `type` attribute isn't present in a `<button>` element it defaults to `type="submit"`.

Comment: I did have it in my code. I removed it before I went home for the weekend and deployed to production. I passed the event into the main function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.preventDefault` does indeed work. As `nnnnnn` pointed out, you dont show where you tried it but I suspect that you were not using it correctly, more than likely, you were not passing the `event` into the handler and `e` or `event` (whatever you named it) was actually `undefined`.  Here is an example of one way to use it properly:

```js
$('.ajax-submit').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("button called");
  //... all your other code here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action="">
<button id="next" class="green-button ajax-submit" > Next</button>
</form>
```